# Setting up webhook receiver with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, postman, webhooks

I'm trying to set up a webhook receiver to receive JSON from a POST from an API running locally.

I'm trying to test out the incoming URI by sending a POST to the incoming URI in Postman but it's erroring out and not hitting my breakpoints in the webhook handler.

This is what I did:

I downloaded the Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Receivers.Generic nuget package.

**WebApiConfig.cs:**

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            config.InitializeReceiveGenericJsonWebHooks();
        }
    }
```

**Webhook handler class:**

```
public class GenericJsonWebHookHandler : WebHookHandler
    {
        public GenericJsonWebHookHandler()
        {
            this.Receiver = "genericjson";
        }

        public override Task ExecuteAsync(string generator, WebHookHandlerContext context)
        {
            // Get JSON from WebHook
            JObject data = context.GetDataOrDefault<JObject>();

            if (context.Id == "i")
            {
                //You can use the passed in Id to route differently depending on source.
            }
            else if (context.Id == "z")
            {
            }

            return Task.FromResult(true);
        }
    }
```

**App settings in Web.config:**

```
`<add key="MS_WebHookReceiverSecret_GenericJson" value="i=1388a6b0d05eca2237f10e4a4641260b0a08f3a5,z=80ad19e357b01a04fe767067df7cd31b96a844e1" />`
```

Tried to send a POST in Postman at this URL: `https://localhost:44386/api/webhooks/incoming/genericjson/z?code=80ad19e357b01a04fe767067df7cd31b96a844e1`. I sent "hello" in the body because some instructions online told me to...

I get a "connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:44386" error.

Comment: Try using http in stead of https?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya that was it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Change from (https):**

```
https://localhost:44386/api/webhooks/incoming/genericjson/z?code=80ad19e357b01a04fe767067df7cd31b96a844e1
```

**To (http):**

```
http://localhost:44386/api/webhooks/incoming/genericjson/z?code=80ad19e357b01a04fe767067df7cd31b96a844e1
```